# Python - script outputs wrong .xml file

Tags: python, xml, server

I have a python script that makes a .xml file. I am running this script on my server. And it runs fine and at the end of the script I put the generated file on my server like this.

```
output_path = "/path_to_my_loication/"
ofname = "name_of_file.xml"
output_file = output_path + ofname
open(output_file, "w").write(str(BeautifulSoup(get_xml(menu_url_list[0][1]))))
```

and is just part of making the file, pretty sure its irrelevant to this. So run the script on my server and it outputs my file, and I can see it, but the url is not correct instead of it being.

```
myserver/path_to_my_loication/name_of_file.xml
```

it is

```
myserver/path_to_my_loication/%0d%0dname_of_file.xml
```

This is being added `%0d%0d` before the file name I am not sure how to fix this, and when I print my file name just before I write the file, the characters are not there? How can I get rid of this/ why does this happen.

When I just run the script on my laptop the file name does not contain theses characters. Is it a server side issues that I should contact my serve provider about?

Thanks for the help.

Okay AIG cause when I printed for my server I saw this, I though enter was just some weird thing

[image]

How can I get rid of the enters?

Here is full code

https://gist.github.com/spennyf/de3349252695cecd4e6c

Comment: Looks like two carriage returns are encoded.

Comment: what does `print  output_file` show?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it prints /path_to_my_loication/name_of_file.xml, that was on my computer give me 5 minutes and ill run it on my server

Comment: In the code you write, `output_path` does not end with a "/", so it cannot produce the desired result. Are you sure your code is correct?

Comment: @AlG what does that mean?

Comment: @Simpom sorry that was just a typo in the question, the file is made and on the web, the problem is the extra charcters

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I ran it on my server and it gave me this "/home/spencerf/public_html/binghamton_university/binghamton_university_chenango_menu.xml" no characters there?

Comment: Two **Enter** key characters are what it put into the filename.

Comment: @AlG how can I fix this, could you please see edit?

Comment: is one windows and the other linux?

Comment: I wrote the script on my mac, and I am not sure what the server is running?

Comment: I'm sure that you are not showing relevant parts of the code. If you only have two hardcoded strings and concatenate them, nothing can go wrong.

Comment: The carriage returns are being added somewhere so if you are not doing it them the server must be. Maybe adding more if your code will help

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have added full code to question, the script was running fine until today, which is why I find this change weird

Comment: @Jasper added code to question if you wouldn't mind taking a look

Comment: I had to use strip `datetime.datetime.strptime(d.strip(), '%m/%d/%Y')` to remove a carriage return from the date

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that is already there, where did you change?

Comment: I added a strip. also `ofname ` outputs `'\r\n                                        1/21/2015 - 1/25/2015\r\n ` so you can see where it comes from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69479/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-padraic-cunningham).